# Boundary shape recognition ignoring scaling

Tags: matlab, opencv, image-processing, artificial-intelligence

I need some shape recognition advice. To be specific, I am data mining photos to recognize the presence of particular shapes, and these shapes may be connected together as well. i.e. the widget1 and widget2 I am interested in may be connected together by some frame.

These widgets may also be of different sizes, which may give issue with template matching techniques. For example, widget1 could be roughly 20x20 pixels in one picture and 100x100 pixels in another. Widget2 can be scaled differently in the same pictures. There can also be issues with pre-processing out some of the labeling/text that may be on these widgets as not to confuse any matching technique used.

Do you guys have any advice in which areas of image processing I should explore?

In summary, the issues are:
1) identifying known shapes
2) scaling differences can exist in the widgets between the photos
3) labeling on the widgets may exist that may confuse the algorithms used above - so should be pre-processed out

Thanks a bunch. If you guys can give some advice on suggested techniques and resources I should read-up on, that would be a great help!

Answer (score 1):

This isn't necessarily a MATLAB or OpenCV question, but I would suggest having a look at [MATLAB's Computer Vision toolbox](http://www.mathworks.com/products/computer-vision/) and browse the [Shape Descriptors](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/structural_analysis_and_shape_descriptors.html) sections of the OpenCV manual.  Also, I realize this isn't a full answer, but there are many solutions to shape and object recognition, and the selected method depends heavily on the specifics of your problem.